# First macro assembler program, can't figure our unhandled exception

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

This is my first assembler program in masm32.  Using vis studio 2012.  And this is just one procedure in a program to convert input into an ascii chart with decimal, hex and ascii output.  I've been trying to figure this out for 8 hours, and I know it's going to be something really simple.
It gets through all the computation, but during the pop and return phase it crashes into an unhandled exception when accessing the EIP(i think).  Also, all my registers are set to 0 except ebx and I don't know why, but it may have something to do with it.

*This is just the procedure to convert from the input string to a decimal value.**

My inputStr is:

```
inputStr   db  16  DUP(0) 

.code
main proc

   xor      eax, eax
   xor      ebx, ebx
   xor      ecx, ecx
   xor      edx, edx

   lea      esi, outputStr1
   call     PrintString
   lea      esi, inputStr
   call     GetString
   call     StrtoNum

   invoke ExitProcess, 0        ;****This is the next line when it crashes***   
main endp

StrtoNum proc  ;going to hex first
    pushad
    pushfd
    mov     bl, 1        ;mov 1 into bl for later multiplying

whilemorechar:
    mov     al,byte ptr [esi]
    cmp     al, 0       ;stuff
    je      ConvertDone      ;if null then we are done here
       ;esi is pointing to the string to be converted
    ;cmp bl,0
    ;jnz decrement
    cmp     al, 0h
    je      ConvertDec
    sub     al, 30h     ;get first string byte to dec number 0-9
    push    ax         ;push last digit to stack
    inc     esi         ;gets to next string byte
    inc     cl          ;make note of decimal position in string
    jmp     whilemorechar      ;jump for next place in string

ConvertDec:             ;reverse is done, now turn into decimal number
    cmp     cl, 0           ;compare counter to 0
    jz      ConvertDone      ;if counter is 0, start comparing numbers
    pop     ax                  ;pop last on stack
    mul     bl                  ;multiply place value by input byte
    add     dx, ax              ;add decimal value into dl
    mov     al, 10d             ;move 10 into al
    mul     bx                  ;multiply 10 and bl value to get next
    mov     bx, ax              ;mov decimal place into bl for next loop 
    dec     cl                  ;decrement counter
    jmp     ConvertDec          ;loop through again for next decimal place

ConvertDone:    
    mov     ebx, 0  
    popfd                   ;pop flags
    popad                   ;pop registers
    ret                     ;return to caller
StrtoNum endp
```

Comment: I assume that this isn't the whole file you're showing here, and that you've got all the setup codes/include files etc? How does the stack look on the return from StrtoNum?

Comment: You don't set cl to zero upon entry to StrToNum are you sure that it is?